# PrimeFaces DataExporter to XLS for multiple Columns not working correctly

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:dataTable>`:

```html
<p:dataTable  id="contracttblenone"  var="contract" value="#{reportController.listcontract}" rowKey="#{contract.id}" paginator="true" rows="10"  paginatorPosition="bottom"           paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" resizableColumns="true" emptyMessage="">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="№"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{contract.id}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Firma Ad?"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{contract.name}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:columns  width="60" value="#{contract.liscolumn}" var="column">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value=" #{column.header} "/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value=" #{column.property} " />   
    </p:columns>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Sirket Sozlesmeler"/>
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

And this is my commandLink:

```html
 <h:commandLink>  
       <p:graphicImage value="../img/xls.png" />  
       <p:dataExporter type="xls" target=":formreport:contracttblenone"
           fileName="report" />  
 </h:commandLink>
```

Here is how the dataTable looks

[image]

But exported xls is different. It is modifying all rowas as last one here is the snaphsot from excel:

[image: x]

Comment: Could you post the `postProcessXLS` method?

Comment: @dratewka It has nothing. I can remove it. Some styles for excel cells.

Comment: Try to export to `type="cvs"` and see how the generated file looks like in a text editor - maybe there's a bug in Primefaces.

Comment: @dratewka I exported it to csv and  the result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I too have some problems in using the exporttoExcel functioanality of primefaces.I have searched a lot on stackoverflow and primefacesForums but just got to know that it's a primefaces related version issue.By the way i have made my own function which is now perfectly working and can also be modified as per exporting to other formats.

```
<p:commandLink  id="back" value="Export to Excel" action="#{agendaBean.exportToExl}" immediate="true" 
                    ajax="false" style="color: #086A87;" ></p:commandLink>
```

After clicking on the link the exportToExl method is called in the bean which has the following contents.

```
public String exportToExl() {

        ExportToExcel expExlBean = new ExportToExcel();

        List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        columnNames.add("Agenda ID");
        columnNames.add("Matter");
        columnNames.add("Item");
        columnNames.add("OrderNo");
        columnNames.add("AccessPrivilegeString");

        columnNames.add("DocumentNameDisplay");
        columnNames.add("DocumentFolderPath");

        List<String> columnType = new ArrayList<String>();
        columnType.add(FrameWorkConstants.DO_NOT_FORMAT);
        columnType.add(FrameWorkConstants.DO_NOT_FORMAT);
        columnType.add(FrameWorkConstants.DO_NOT_FORMAT);
        columnType.add(FrameWorkConstants.DO_NOT_FORMAT);
        columnType.add(FrameWorkConstants.DO_NOT_FORMAT);
        columnType.add(FrameWorkConstants.DO_NOT_FORMAT);
        columnType.add(FrameWorkConstants.DO_NOT_FORMAT);

        String companyFolderPath = new AgendaIMPL()
                .getCompanyFolderPath(meetingID);
        if (agendaList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < agendaList.size(); i++) {
                agendaList.get(i).setDocumentFolderPath(companyFolderPath);
            }
        }
        List expList = agendaList;

        if (expList == null || expList.isEmpty()) {
            ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle
                    .getBundle("resources.error1");
            if (rb != null) {
                Utils.addMessage(rb.getString("34").trim(),
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                return null;
            }
        }

        String strVOName = "com.ultimatix.boardAdmin.vo.AgendaVO";

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();

        String flagStart = FrameWorkConstants.SINGLE;
        expExlBean.exportToExcel(columnNames, columnType, response,
                expList, strVOName, flagStart);

        fc.responseComplete();
    return null;
}
```

Here AgendaList is the list you are using in the datatable to populate rows.which you want to print in the excel Sheet.

Let me know incase you feel any more concerned issues.

Comment: i am new bie in using primefaces exports, can you say me what is "FrameworkConstants.DO_NOT_FOMRAT" because my eclipse is out of scope finding it.

Comment: i think you can help in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889066/issue-with-primefaces-pdataexporter-which-exports-a-datatable-with-selectoneme/24893436#comment38744547_24893436