# Issue with Primefaces p:dataExporter, which exports a DataTable with SelectOneMenu not as expected?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, data-export

I want to Export the `<p:dataTable>` which has a SelectOneMenu as shown in this Example [JSF Primefaces SelectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146896/jsf-primefaces-selectonemenu)

So, i used the primefaces `<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="datatbleId" fileName="cars"/>`

which `generated a xls file` as the below format:

```
------------------------------------
Name | Car 
----------------------------------------
ABC | 1
DDD | 2
```

What should i do ? So, that i can generate a `xls` in the below format :

```
------------------------------------
Name | Car 
----------------------------------------
ABC | Toyota
DDD | Ford
```

**My DataTable Code Looks like this:**

```
<p:dataTable id="studentDtble" var="studentDetail" value="#{studentController.studentList}" emptyMessage="No records found">
    <p:column styleClass="ralign">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Student Id " />
        </f:facet>
        <p:commandLink id="studentCmdLnk" action="#{profileHandler.showStudentProfile}" update=":tabView:loanOvrviewForm">
            <h:outputText id="studentIdOutTxt" value="#{studentDetail.studentId}" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Class" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="classoutTxt" value="#{studentDetail.class}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Student Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="nameoutTxt" value="#{studentDetail.studentName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Contact No" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText id="contactInTxt" value="#{studentDetail.studentContact}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="DOJ" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="dojDateOutTxt" value="#{studentDetail.dojDate}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Group/Branch" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="branchesLstBox" value="#{studentDetail.branchList.branchId}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{studentController.getAllBranches()}" var="branches" itemValue="#{branches.branchId}" itemLabel="#{branches.branchName}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Remarks" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:inputText id="remarksInTxt" value="#{studentDetail.remarks}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: @BalusC might help you out :) I think this does'nt need a DataExporter as defined by Sujan below

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do it with dataExporter, however you can implement your own exporter, it's quite easy, you just need Apache POI.

Sample :

A button to put in the facelet.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s" value="XLS" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)">
<p:fileDownload  value="#{dataExporter.generateXLS()}" />                       
</p:commandButton >
```

A request scoped managed bean (but you can implement a webservlet too)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

@ManagedBean(name="dataExporter")
@RequestScoped
public class DataExporter  {

 public StreamedContent generateXLS() {

        if (list != null) { // the list you are using in the data Table
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                String filePath = "E:\\tmp\\";
                String fileName = "xlsFile";
                String a = filePath + fileName;
                XSSFWorkbook new_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
                XSSFSheet sheet = new_workbook.createSheet("SAMPLE"); 
                int cellnum = 0;
                int rownum = 0 ;
                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

                 for (Object object : list) { //loop through the data and add them to the cell
                    row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                    cellnum = 0;

                    cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                    if (object.getColumn1() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(object.getColumn1());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                    if (object.getColumn2() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(object.getColumn2());
                    }
                   }

                   FileOutputStream output_file = null;
                try {
                    output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(a)); 
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

                }

                try {
                    new_workbook.write(output_file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }

                try {
                    output_file.close(); //close the file
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(a);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

                }
                InputStream is = fis;
                String mimeType = "";
                try {
                    mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }

                return new DefaultStreamedContent(is, mimeType, fileName);
            }
```

**Disclaimer** : Not tested, and you need to adapt the code with your own objects and entities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) will work around with this and post it back

Comment: While working around with the Code posted, i think, this goes complex if we have a datatable with 'n' no of Columns defined, Dont we have any other way to generate the Excel using the "p:dataExporter" itself.

Comment: @Robin Hood's Did you tried the solution given by Sujan.Is it a good practise

Comment: @09Q71AO534 No i didnt tried the Solution ;), i just referred the problem, i hope the Excel Generator by #Sujan should work :), but thinking it globally i can say that they might be a problem while we have dynamic no of Columns in a DataTable.

Comment: @Sujan is it that important to create a new DataExporter, just because of SelectOneMenu item Label, i think it might be handled some other way :). i am not that much aware of primefaces but i googled and noticed that BalusC having the reputation on answering such questions.

Comment: @09Q71AO534 You can modify the code to make it dynamic. i.e : find all fields of an entity, create the columns and fill the rows accordingly.

Comment: @Robin Hood's I don't think it works out of the box. Anyway, what is passed to dataExporter is of course **not** the label but the value.

Comment: @09Q71AO534 You need to post your code for the dataTable.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan What i believed is just because of one case failure we should not go back to the starting phase of design.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I tried rectifying the code which you posted, but my eclipse find difficulties in (//loop through the data and add them to the cell )Can you make the post much clear.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan yes , i do read the disclaimer, but do u think posting an un-tested code into RealWorld can work ;). I said i just tried and then the code which u wrote is thrown by eclipse :P.So i suggested to check it once nothing much sir :)

Comment: @RobinHood's I can't post real code without real code, that's why I asked the OP to post his dataTable code ;) P.S: I have a similar method in one of my app and it works perfectly.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan i agree ;) with you :) the OP should have post the code

Comment: @First, Sorry for all for the late. i think the discussion between Sujan sir and Robin sir is cool. I will edit my question with the datatable in few min. :)

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan might help you out now, with the code you posted. 09Q71A0534 :)

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan sir did u find any workaround :) on this issue

Comment: @09Q71AO534 Hello, did you solve the problem or still struggling with  ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I did'nt find a Solution for this yet :( but i had a partial fix which we can say it as Hard code.